# my transaction is still uncormed after 48+ hours

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, blockchain.info, blockchain-fork

I was sent money to my coinbase account and it is still unconfirmed, this is the longest transaction yet for me. can anyone help?

hash id: 9cca279484347e0e17a2a40f3e38fc62e91db0e4c4bd2834f5a504e1ed628733

Answer (score 0):

You only attached ~$2 in fees. The average transaction fee right now is ~$40<sup>[source](https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin/)</sup>. It will take a while, if ever, to confirm.